# When the ring of regular functions is Artinian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties

Let $K$ be a field, $W$ an algebraic variety over $K$ and $A(W)=\{f:W\rightarrow K \mid f \text{ regular}\}$ the ring of regular functions. When is $A(W)$ an Artinian ring?

I know that $A(W)$ is a reduced finitely generated $K$-algebra, and I have tried to stabilize a descending chain $I_1\supseteq I_2 \supseteq \dots$ but I have not even fount a sufficient condition.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A sufficient condition is that $X$ is proper over $K$.

Comment: By $X$ you mean $W$ or something that I am missing? If $X=W$ I still do not see how that suffices for $A(X)$ to be artinian.

Comment: I meant $W$. This is a standard result. I do not know your background, so can not explain in a comment. Most standard texts will give you a proof ( Hartshorne, Shafarevich, Mumford).

Comment: If $ X $ is proper and your definition of variety includes 'irreducible' then the global regular functions infact form a finite field extension of $ K $.